# Html link to mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, html

This is a curiosity: can I link a pure HTML page to database? Or I have to use an ASP.NET/PHP/other(?) web language that uses script?

Comment: You will have to use a server side programming language (like PHP, ASP.NET, etc.) to communicate with the database.

Comment: you cant do it without server side languages

Comment: It's surprising that the user who asked this question, the user who commented, and the user who answered are all sharing a common name :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** link to a database with the help of HTML only.

HTML is a simple markup language, inorder to link to the Database, you need to use a server side language such as **JSP**, **ASP** or **PHP**.

If you want some sort of data storage mechanism, you can use **Local Storage API** for that.

But beware that the data you store will *reside on the clients browser* and not on your machine, so if they clear out the files on their browsers, the data will be lost.

Also, storing sensitive information using Local Storage isn't recommended. I would suggest you to use that ONLY IF you have basic requirements.

[Here's a good article](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) to get you started with HTML5 Local Storage API

Answer (score 2):

HTML is markup, and is not capable of linking to a database.

For that, you'd need a server side language such as PHP. However you could use AJAX which loads a server side script on another page which would in turn link to the database, but this page would need to contain some JavaScript.